# How to open "." files for editing with text editors on macintosh

Tags: macos

"." files like ".bashrc" are invisible to the finder. How do you make them visible so you can open then inside editors like textedit or sublime?

Comment: Can you just open the editor and then go the menu, click open, and then type the full name? I also know that on Linux `Ctrl-H` makes those files not hidden anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any method to make these files visible from the Finder (there may well be one, though), but if you want to edit a `.bashrc`, you are apparently familiar with the shell anyway.

Open a Terminal, and from the shell, open the file like this:

```
open -a /Applications/TextEdit.app .bashrc
```

You need to speficy the application to open it with because the default one is the shell, which is not helpful in this case.

**Update:** Pressing ⇧⌘. (Command-Shift-Period) makes the hidden files visible in a Finder window. Pressing that again hides them.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal, then type the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

If you are in an Open or Save dialog, you can use CONTROL+SHIFT+PERIOD.

Comment: I can't comment on others' posts yet (insufficient reputation), but since you are using Sublime Text, you can also type `subl <filename>` in Terminal without having to use the `open` command and specifying the full path to the app.